# How to specify file type for a variable, in the model file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-4, model

In one of my model files I would like to specify for a variable (called xml_file) that it should be an xml file. What I've tried so far generated error messages.

**Attempt 1**

```
validates  :xml_file,         presence: true,
                              content_type: %w(application/xml)
```

On `rake test` this generated the error `ArgumentError: Unknown validator: 'ContentTypeValidator'`.

**Attempt 2**

```
VALID_XML_REGEX = %w(xml)
validates  :xml_file,         presence: true,
                              format: { with: VALID_XML_REGEX }
```

This on testing generated the error `ArgumentError: A regular expression or a proc or lambda must be supplied as :with`.

**Attempt 3**: Create its own method

```
validates  :xml_file_format
private
def xml_file_format
  validates :xml_file, format: /.xml/
end
```

This didn't work either and generated the error `ArgumentError: You need to supply at least one validation`.

Therefore, my question: *how to specify the variable 'xml_file' should be an xml file in the model file?*

Comment: %w creates an array, not a regex. Just use ```/```'s
VALID_XML_REGEX = /.xml /. Or better yet make a method that takes that file and checks its extname, and then validate with that method.

Comment: Thanks I added my attempt to validate using a method as "attempt 3". But that doesn't seem to be the right way.

Comment: This is not self promotion and I care very little for reputation points but many other have found my answer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818251/how-to-validate-file-content-type-to-pdf-word-excel-and-plain-text-for-paperc/14650432) useful so I thought I would share. While it pertains to paperclip directly modifying it for your purposes would not be very difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confounding 2 separate things:

1. XML file
2. Path to an XML file

You are validating the Path to an XML file, which does not have a content_type. (AAMOF, XML files don't have a `content_type` either, but that is a separate topic.)

According to the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format), you can use:

```
format: { with: /\.xml\z/ }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried an adapted version of attempt 3 (as I understand it's better to use a method): 
`validates :xml_file_format` 
`private def xml_file_format` 
 `validates :xml_file, format: { with: /\.xml\z/ }` 
`end`.   But this still generated the error message `ArgumentError: You need to supply at least one validation` referring to the first line.

Comment: If you use a method, I think `validate` needs to be singular: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate

Comment: Great. I think you need to use something like `errors.add ... unless xml_file.match /\.xml\z/ `

Comment: I believe `def xml_file_format` `errors.add(:xml_file, "File format error") unless (xml_file.match(/\.xml\z/))` `end` does the trick.

Comment: Yes, that looks good. FWIW, since the validation is only one line, it may not need to be a separate method...

Comment: Is there no advantage of having it as a **private** method?

Comment: No, I don't think there is an advantage in having it in a private method. Who else would access it?